# Get Results from INNER JOIN on same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's I have a inner join which results in a table as follows

```
WORKFLOWID  Value
1           One
1           Two
2           Three
2           Four
```

But what I want for this is one record to come back

```
ID    Value1 Value2
1     One    Two
2     Three  Four
```

What options do I have in SQL to change an inner join to behave as above ?

```
SELECT ws.workflow_id as WorkflowId, sg.unmatched_value as UnmatchedValue
FROM [geo_workflow_step] as ws 
INNER JOIN [geo_workflow] as gw on ws.workflow_id = gw.id
INNER JOIN [geo_super_group] as sg on gw.super_group_id = sg.ID
order by WorkflowId
```

Comment: what RDBMS do you use?

Comment: None. Joins are for connecting data together, what you are searching for is display. Could you show us the query?

Comment: For Value of the same WORKFLOWID, are there at most two values? Is it ok Value1 = 'Two' AND Value2 = 'One'? If Value2 must be less Value1 in English, we need to translate them somehow.

Comment: `SELECT ws.workflow_id, MIN(sg.unmatched_value) AS Value1, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(sg.unmatched_value) END AS Value2 FROM (ws INNER JOIN gw INNER JOIN sg) GROUP BY ws.workflow_id ORDER BY ws.workflow_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select t1.workflowid as id,
       min(t1.value) as value1,
       max(t2.value) as value2
from the_table t1
  join the_table t2 
    on t1.workflowid = t2.workflowid
   and t1.value <> t2.value
group by t1.workflowid
```

This assumes that there are always exactly two rows present in the table. If this is not the case, you will indeed lookup the `PIVOT` operator (search for it, there are tons of questions for that on SO)

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97e8b/2

Comment: Just looking at that query...you get Value from two different tables ? In my case Value comes from the same table.

Comment: @StevieB: no, it's a self-join on **one** table (named `the_table` in this example)

Comment: Gotcha..also in my case I will always have Maximum two rows present but there is also a chance 1 will return for some. How would this handle that ?

Comment: @StevieB: then use an outer join.

Comment: Looking at the OP's query, there is no need to join the query against itself; which is potentially expensive and certainly redundant.  The OP's query can be updated with a simple `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `MAX` for `Value1` and `Value2` respectfully, using a `CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1` to force `Value2` to `NULL` in the event of only having 1 value.  *(See my comment on the OP.)*

Comment: @MatBailie: good point and I do agree with you - however the real query wasn't in the question when I answered ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WORKFLOWID ORDER BY WORKFLOWID) 
 FROM TableName)

SELECT WORKFLOWID,MAX(Value1) as Value1,MAX(Value2) as Value2
FROM
(SELECT WORKFLOWID,
       CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN Value END as Value1,
       CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN Value END as Value2
FROM CTE) T
GROUP BY WORKFLOWID
```

Result:

```
WORKFLOWID  VALUE1   VALUE2
1           One      Two
2           Three    Four
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f137/27).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Id int,value varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (1,
        'one'),(1,
                'Two'), (2,
                         'three'),(2,
                                   'four') ;

WITH CTE AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT t.Id,
                    t.value AS value1,
                    tt.value AS value2,
                    ROW_NUMBER()over(partition BY t.id
                                     ORDER BY t.id)AS RN
   FROM @t t
   INNER JOIN @t tt ON t.Id = tt.Id
   AND t.value <> tt.value )
SELECT ID,
       value1,
       value2
FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1
```